# How to create a tunnel after ssh to remote machine using private key using bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a server where i will be logging into the server from my local machine and create a tunnel.

I have a bash script which is not creating tunnel

```
sshpass -p ${1} ssh ${2}@${3}
ssh -L <port1>:<host>:80 -i /home/<user>/private_key <user_ID>@<host2>
```

Result i am getting -

```
sh ssh_to_box.sh pwd username remotehost
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-145-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

144 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release '18.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.


*** System restart required ***
Last login: Thu May 30 09:36:36 2019 from remotehost
$
```

Script is not doing tunneling.
Also it should do $bash

How to ssh to remote and create tunnel from that remote machine and keep the tunnel alive?

Comment: Your second command doesn't run until the first one exits. You probably want a *single* `ssh` command that uses the `ProxyJump` option.

Comment: Are you expecting the second `ssh` command to run on your local host, or on host `$3`?

Comment: i want to run ssh command on host $3

Comment: Solved the issue - 

sshpass -p ${1} ssh -t ${2}@${3} 'ssh -L '${4}':'${5}':'${6}' -i /home/<Path>_key '${2}'@'${7}''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue - sshpass -p ${1} ssh -t ${2}@${3} 'ssh -L '${4}':'${5}':'${6}' -i /home/_key '${2}'@'${7}''

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are in fact creating the tunnel, you should check if

```
ss -lptn | awk '{ print $4 }' | awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' | sed -e '/<port1>/!d'
```

Is returning something when the ssh console is opened, if true you have a tunnel.
(May there is a better way to do this check but I didn't know very well awk)

If you want the tunnel to be persistent may you execute it inside tmux/screen or run `nohup <tunnel_command> &`

It's important to note that  name will be dns resolved by the remote host also.

Comment: Good Stuff ! and wonderfully illustrates the power of `*nix` pipes for one-off explorations as this ;-) . As  you probably know, It can be boiled down to something like `ss ...|awk '{split($4,arr,":");if (arr[2] ~ /<port1>/)print arr[2]}'` which is better for code that will run inside of a loop millions of times in a day, running 3 (or more) processes instead of 1 will consume unneeded system resources. (Not that this is the case here). Keep posting and good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter Sorry, I don't know awk too much so I use it in a very basic way. I will learn it soon :)

Comment: [Awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) will get you towards guru-hood in a few hours ;-)  (but at your convenience ;-) ). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Thank you I'll check